# algorithm to check whether a given graph is subgraph of another graph

Tags: graph, np-complete, subgraph, isomorphism

i assume that we have 2 labeled graphs G and T and the algorithm determine if G a subgraph of T and the corresponding vertices in the main graphT and the subgraph G should have same label

Comment: Just a note on the side, the [Subgraph isomorphism problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgraph_isomorphism_problem) is NP-complete.

Answer (score 3):

That problem is called ["subgraph isomorphism"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgraph_isomorphism_problem) and it is NP-complete (and so likely to be hard).  Do you need a general solution for this, or just for a particular graph `G`?  The second case is much easier.  There is some general information about algorithms [here](http://ai.stanford.edu/~suresh/theory/references/MCS.txt).  There is a version of one of the algorithms (actually, for a more general problem) in the Boost Graph Library (see documentation [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/graph/doc/mcgregor_common_subgraphs.html)).

Comment: +1 for being first and citing a 1993 thread on the matter :)

Comment: @phooji: A lot of the results haven't changed, most likely; I know Nauty is still used, at least, though I've heard of it from the full graph isomorphism problem.  The algorithm I mention from my edit is from 1982.

Comment: @Jeremiah Willcock: 1993... 1982... what's next? 1971? ;)

Comment: i need a general algorithm for graph isomorphism problem

Comment: @fayza: Graph isomorphism or subgraph isomorphism?

Answer (score 2):

A general answer for a general question: the problem you want to solve is known as 'subgraph isomorphism.' Have a look here for further references: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgraph_isomorphism_problem .